# What are the meanings of the TShark tcp.flags.str labels?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tshark

I am working with `tshark` and I've extracted a field called: `tcp.flags.str`. I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of these field values. For example, a few strings might look like:

```
·······A····
··········S·
·······A···F
····C··AP···
RRR·CE····S·
·······A·R·F
·R···EUAPRSF
··RN········
```

I've worked out that the entire filled string is: `RRRNCEUAPRSF`, and I'm guessing that `A`: ACK, `S`: SYN, `P`: PUSH, `U`: URGENT, `F`: FIN, `C`: Congestion Window Reduced. Otherwise, I have no guesses other than that there are some `R` values, so somewhere there's a RESET and RESERVED, but I have no idea where. Where can I find some good documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 793 section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.1) defines the original 6 TCP flags.  [RFC 3168](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3168#section-6.1) introduced the ECN-Echo and Congestion Window Reduced flags.  [RFC 3540](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3540) introduced the Nonce Sum flag, but which Wireshark/tshark refers to as Accurate ECN, presumably from [RFC 7560](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7560).  The remaining 3 bits of the TCP flags field are still marked as Reserved.  Thus, `RRRNCEUAPRSF` stands for:

- RRR = Reserved for future use
- N = Nonce sum (NS, now referred to as "Accurate ECN")
- C = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR)
- E = ECN-Echo (ECE)
- U = Urgent (URG)
- A = Acknowledgement (ACK)
- P = Push (PSH)
- R = Reset (RST)
- S = Synchronize (SYN)
- F = Finish (FIN)

Comment: Thanks! Question about `RRR`: why do I see these three "fields" populated at varying rates? My intuition is that "reserved for future use" means they are not currently being used and yet, I see them populated.

Comment: Well, [RFC 793 Section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.1) states that the reserved bits must be zero, so if they're not zero, then either the application setting those bits is being careless and in violation of the RFC, or perhaps it's using them for some other unknown purpose.  Or perhaps it's a "fuzz tester" that sets random bits to test the behavior of the sender and/or receiver of these packets in how it handles them.  If I were to guess, then I'd probably go with the first case - the application is simply in violation of the RFC and ideally it could be fixed.

Comment: The most recent definition of the TCP flags is in [Fig 2 of IETF draft-ietf-tcpm-accurate-ecn](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tcpm-accurate-ecn#section-3.1.1), which has not yet been approved as an RFC, but Wireshark has added support on the assumption it will be soon: